# get underlying response stream from WebOperationContext

Tags: wcf, streaming

How do I get access to the underlying response stream from a WebOperationContext?

Comment: If you tell us what you are trying to do we could suggest the best way to do it with WCF, 'cause the short answer is you're not supposed to.

Comment: Actually I'm not even sure this would work, I have a download service that zips up directories when a directory is requested, instead of writing the zip file to disk then streaming the file to the user, I'd rather right directly to the response stream.

Comment: eh, thats "write directly" not "right directly"

Answer (score 0):

Change the return type of the method to Stream.

The code I use for returning an html/text stream is:

```
  public Stream GetHTML()
  {

      MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
      StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
      writer.Write("HTML STRING");

      conn.Close();

      writer.Flush();
      stream.Position = 0;

      WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/html";

      return stream;
   }
```

Obviously you'll have a different content type, and I don't think you'll have to use UTF8 encoding.